# pretrained inception model always predicts crane

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, imagenet

I am using keras inception pretrained model (using imagenet data) 
    https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/applications/inception_v3.py

My short program is

```
model = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet')

img_path = 'data/rockcliff.jpg'
img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(299, 299))
x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
x = preprocess_input(x)

preds = model.predict(x)
print('Predicted:', decode_predictions(preds))
```

I tried 3 images, cropped_panda, rockcliff, and pitcher. In every case the prediction returns crane as the top choice. The exact return is

('Predicted:', [[(u'n03126707', u'crane', 0.77817649), (u'n04041544', u'radio', 0.098524272), (u'n03450230', u'gown', 0.084664099), (u'n02128925', u'jaguar', 0.015732178), (u'n03459775', u'grille', 0.011028509)]])

Any idea what's the problem?

Comment: Are the values of the predictions exactly the same in each of the 3 cases?

Comment: Try to visualize x after preprocessing. Might be your preprocessing doing smth wrong.